Nautilus: Change alt-down from "back" to "down"
I'm on 24.04 & in Nautilus, using alt and an arrow key yields largely sensible navigation behaviour:

left: back [if previously elsewhere]
right: forward [if previously elsewhere]
up: up one level of the hierarchy
down: same as left

But I would have expected down, if a directory is highlighted, to enter said directory. Is there any way to modify the keyboard shortcuts to achieve this?

No, there isn't.
